# Salesforce Apex - ObfuscateUser (invocable for 1 userId from Flow)

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I've been working on this with no success (I'm a newbie to code). I'm trying to take this code for obfuscateUser and update it for the following:

1. make it invocable from Salesforce Flow
2. accept *one* incoming UserId to obfuscate

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Related Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm

```
public class UserManagementController{
    public List <User> users {get; set;}
    
    public UserManagementController()
    {
        Profile p = [select id from profile where name = 'Customer Community User'];
        
        users = [select username, id from User where profileId=:p.id AND isactive=true];
    }

    //Use method with extreme caution. Data can't be recovered.   
    @InvocableMethod(label='User Management' description='Obfuscate User data and more')
    static public void obfuscate(List<User> users)
    {
        String uid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uid');
        
        if(uid == null)
            return;
        
        User u = [select contactId from user where id=:uid];
            
        System.UserManagement.obfuscateUser(uid);
        
        if(u.contactId != null)
        {
            List <Contact> contacts = [select id from Contact where id=:u.contactId LIMIT 1];
            if (contacts == null || contacts.isEmpty() == true)
            return;
                
            delete contacts;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you've got is for implementing this from a list view I believe.  I've updated it below to be a fairly straightforward invocable method.  I'm sure you've figured it out by now, but for anyone else looking!

```java
public class UserManagementController {
  
  //Use method with extreme caution. Data can't be recovered.   
  @InvocableMethod(label='User Management' description='Obfuscate User data and more')
  static public void obfuscate(List<Id> ids)
  {
    for (Id id : ids) {
      System.UserManagement.obfuscateUser(id);
    }
     
}
```